# Different Behavior Between Debug and Release Builds

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm using the [SOCKit](https://github.com/jverkoey/sockit) library to implement a URL router for my app. I have a custom `Router` class that keeps track of all the valid routes and implements a `match` method that, given a route `NSString`, matches it to a corresponding view controller. To make things easier, the matchable view controllers must implement the `Routable` protocol, which requires an `initWithState:` method that takes an `NSDictionary` as a parameter. Here's the relevant code:

```
- (id)match:(NSString *)route
{
  for (NSArray *match in routePatterns) {
    const SOCPattern * const pattern = [match objectAtIndex:kPatternIndex];
    if ([pattern stringMatches:route]) {
      Class class = [match objectAtIndex:kObjectIndex];

      NSLog(@"[pattern parameterDictionaryFromSourceString:route]: %@", [pattern parameterDictionaryFromSourceString:route]);

      UIViewController<Routable> *vc;
      vc = [[class alloc] initWithState:[pattern parameterDictionaryFromSourceString:route]];
      return vc;
    }
  }
  return nil;
}
```

When I run the app with the `debug` configuration, `[pattern parameterDictionaryFromSourceString:route]` produces what is expected:

```
[pattern parameterDictionaryFromSourceString:route]: {
    uuid = "e9ed6708-5ad5-11e1-91ca-12313810b404";
}
```

On the other hand, when I run the app with the `release` configuration, `[pattern parameterDictionaryFromSourceString:route]` produces an empty dictionary. I'm really not sure how to debug this. I've checked my own code to see if there are any obvious differences between the `debug` and `release` builds to no avail and have also looked at the [SOCKit source code](https://github.com/jverkoey/sockit/blob/master/SOCKit.m). Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that, this has been fixed in https://github.com/jverkoey/sockit/commit/8e666d78ad6c888c72aaa00cdbadcd2da6ebf65d now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into this issue myself today. The issue in my case was that Release builds blocked assertions, but in `-performSelector:onObject:sourceString:` and `-parameterDictionaryFromSourceString:` is this important line:

```
NSAssert([self gatherParameterValues:&values fromString:sourceString],
  @"The pattern can't be used with this string.");
```

Which, when assertions are converted to no-ops, vanishes, and the gathering never happens. With no parameter values, not much happens! I changed it to the following (and will submit an issue to the GitHub repo):

```
if( ![self gatherParameterValues:&values fromString:sourceString] ) {
  NSAssert(NO, @"The pattern can't be used with this string.");
  return nil;
}
```

---

**EDIT:** reported as [issue #13](https://github.com/jverkoey/sockit/issues/13).

Comment: This has been fixed in https://github.com/jverkoey/sockit/commit/8e666d78ad6c888c72aaa00cdbadcd2da6ebf65d

Comment: Ah thanks for figuring that out! Good catch. I was under a crunch when I realized something was wrong, so I just hacked some code to not use SOCKit. I'll go back to using SOCKit now, though!